# Getting multiple results in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know student - student ID, first name, last name. Those have not seen an event at a particular given Auditorium. I have to list these students in ascending last name order (through one query). Run the query twice, showing results for the Auditorium “London Theatre” in one run and “Brentwood Hall” in the second run.

I have no clue what this first and second run means. Also please check if the below will work for first run. I am thinking of creating a view and storing the first run, and writing the same query with "Brentwood Hall" and storing it in the second view. However, how will I display 2 views as part of same query then?

```
SELECT op.StudentID
     , s.FirstName
     , s.LastName 
  FROM auditorium a 
  JOIN audievent e
    ON a.auditoriumID = e.AuditoriumID 
  JOIN reserver r
    ON e.EventID = r.EventID 
  JOIN OrderProcessor op
    ON r.OrderID = op.OrderID 
  JOIN Student s
    ON op.StudentID = s.StudentID 
 WHERE op.StudentID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT op.StudentID 
                                        FROM OrderProcessor op 
                                        LEFT 
                                        JOIN reserver r 
                                          ON op.OrderID = r.OrderID 
                                        LEFT 
                                        JOIN AudiEvent e
                                          ON r.AuditoriumID = e.AuditoriumID 
                                       WHERE e.EventID NOT IN ( SELECT EventID FROM reserver)
                            ) 
   AND a.AuditoriumName = 'London Theatre' 
 GROUP 
    BY op.StudentID;
```

OUTPUT:-

`StudentID   FirstName   LastName
ID1          Andy          Hall
ID2          Andy          Halls
ID3          Mush          Peters
ID4          Garry         Hiegl`

INPUT:-

Auditorium

`AudiID   AudiName
Audi01    London Theatre
Audi02    Brentwood Hall
Audi03    County Hall`

AudiEvent

`EventID  AudiID
1        Audi01
2        Audi01
3        Audi01
4        Audi01
5        Audi01
6        Audi01
7        Audi01
8        Audi01
9        Audi01
10       Audi01
11       Audi02
12       Audi02
13       Audi02
14       Audi02
15       Audi02
16       Audi03
17       Audi03
18       Audi03
19       Audi03
20       Audi03`

Reserver

`ReserverID    OrderID    AudiID    EventID
1              1          Audi01     1
2              1          Audi01     2
3              2          Audi01     3
4              2          Audi01     4
5              2          Audi02     14
6              3          Audi02     15
7              3          Audi02     11
8              4          Audi03     18
9              4          Audi03     19
10             4          Audi03     20`

OrderProcessor

`OrderID    StudentID
1            ID01
2            ID02
3            ID03
4            ID04`

Student

`StudentID   FirstName   LastName
ID1           Andy         Hall
ID2           Andy         Halls
ID3           Mush         Peters
ID4           Garry        Hiegl`

Comment: Given that the above works, for now  the simplest way to get what you want would be to use a UNION with a copy of the first statement above with your changes to the predicate "brentwood hall" OR simply having two selects one after the other. I think this could probably be re-written though.

Comment: I have to fetch the values in the form of 2 runs. First run should show Auditorium 'London Theatre' and the second run should show it as 'Brentwood Hall'. Union wont suffice, as it will show me the members of both halls plus the common ones. This will not fulfil my requirement.

Comment: I am thinking of storing the values of both the auditorium names in View1, and then fetch the value of 2nd Auditorium name from the newly created view? But i think logically that isnt correct either.

Comment: Is there an sqlfiddle?

Comment: `WHERE e.EventID NOT IN ( SELECT r.EventID FROM reserver)` -->> `WHERE e.EventID NOT IN ( SELECT r2.EventID FROM reserver r2)` ASO: `NOT IN (SELECT distinct ...)` the distinct is not needed (and IN(..) is dangerous; in most cases you should use NOT EXISTS(...) )

Comment: `"Run the query twice..."` probably means literally that, simply swapping out the value of the input parameter in `AND a.AuditoriumName = 'London Theatre'`.  Otherwise, ask your instructor for clarification.  As a side note, you're not getting correct results - if you want students who haven't seen an event at `'London Theatre'`, the answer is `'ID3'` and `'ID4'`...

Comment: I'm assuming that the difference in student ids (`'ID1'` vs `'ID01'`) is a simple typo.  As is the differences in column names in your table data versus your example query.  Which is getting the exact opposite results of what your stated goal is (and doesn't match the results you say you _are_ getting)...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse-It is ID01.

Comment: @wildplasser - Why is using IN clause dangerous? I am pretty much used to using it.

Comment: @Strawberry-No i dont have sqlfiddle with me.

Comment: @MrCoder: basically, because it removes NULLs from the resulting list, which may cause surprises if the field happens to be NULLable.

Answer (score 1):

As @wildplasser mentioned, `NOT EXISTS` is *perfect* for this:

```
SELECT studentId, student.firstName, student.lastName
FROM Student
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM OrderProcessor
                  JOIN Reserver
                    ON Reserver.orderId = OrderProcessor.orderId
                  JOIN AudiEvent
                    ON AudiEvent.eventId = Reserver.eventId
                  JOIN Auditorium 
                    ON Auditorium.audiId = AudiEvent.audiId
                       AND Auditorium.audiName = 'London Theatre'
                  WHERE OrderProcessor.studentId = Student.studentId)
```

(working [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27138/4))
The necessary changes to get students who haven't seen events at the `'Brentwood Hall'` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I am getting all the studentIDs after running this query.

Comment: Then you're leaving something out (either when transcribing the query to your system, or in your question).  Did you check the fiddle?  I make it a point to test every query I reasonably can, specifically to verify to myself it works the way I expect.  It _could_ be the definition/value of `Auditorium.auditoriumName` - is it `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` (which may need to be trimmed), is that the actual spelling of `'Theatre'` (as opposed to `'Theater'`), etc.